# Xamarin Forms ImageSource BindableProperty

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un custome tool bar para Xamarin Forms , pero no logro ver mi clase renderizada.
Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?
Me da este error en el Image Source

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver tampo veo el texto aunque ya existe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi implementation class:

```
    public class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    StackLayout mainLayout = new StackLayout();
    Button btn1;
    Label lbl1;
    MainViewModel viewModel;
    ToolBarCustome tbcustome = new ToolBarCustome();
    public MainPage()
    {
        BindingContext = viewModel = new MainViewModel();
        viewModel.Title = "Main Page";            
        Title = viewModel.Title;
        tbcustome.TextProp = Title;
        tbcustome.ImageProp = FileImageSource.FromFile("ino50.png");
        SetUpUI();
    }        
    private void SetUpUI()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetTitleView(this, tbcustome);
        btn1 = new Button();
        lbl1 = new Label();
        btn1.Text = "click me ";
        lbl1.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
        lbl1.Text = "Hi, I'm hardcoded, that is a bad practice";
        btn1.Clicked += GoBack;
        mainLayout.Children.Add(lbl1);
        mainLayout.Children.Add(btn1);
        mainLayout.Padding = 30;
        this.Content = mainLayout;
    }
    private void GoBack(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
```

Y aqui donde defino mi tool bar:

```
    public class ToolBarCustome : ContentView
{
    public static BindableProperty TitleTextProp =
        BindableProperty.Create
        (
            nameof(TextProp),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(ToolBarCustome),
            defaultValue: string.Empty,
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
            propertyChanged: TitleTextPropChanged
        );

    private static void TitleTextPropChanged(BindableObject bindable,
        object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (ToolBarCustome)bindable;
        control.TextProp = newValue?.ToString();
    }

    public string TextProp
    {
        get { return base.GetValue(TitleTextProp)?.ToString(); }
        set { base.SetValue(TitleTextProp, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageSourceProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(ImageProp),
        typeof(ImageSource),
        typeof(ToolBarCustome),
        defaultValue: null,
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay
            );
    
    public ImageSource ImageProp
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    Image image = new Image();
    Label label = new Label();
    StackLayout layout = new StackLayout();

    public ToolBarCustome()
    {
        layout.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        image.Source = ImageProp;
        label.Text = TextProp;
        layout.Children.Add(image);
        layout.Children.Add(label);                       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok asi lo resolvi, de momento utilice un xaml.cs

Parece ser que me faltaba arreglar el binding, utilizando el **x:Name** , hasta donde he encontrado el **x:Name** no esta disponible como tal en puro .cs , podemos usar el **Id** prop, pero no he logrado conseguirlo hasta con el perfomance del xaml.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="animations.Views.CustomViews.ToolBarCustomeXaml"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label x:Name="Lable1" />
            <Image x:Name="Image1" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Y Aqui la implementacion del .cs

```
 public partial class ToolBarCustomeXaml : ContentView
{
    public string TitleText
    {
        get
        {
            return base.GetValue(TitleTextProperty)?.ToString();
        }

        set
        {
            base.SetValue(TitleTextProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty TitleTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TitleText),
      typeof(string),
      typeof(ToolBarCustomeXaml),
      defaultValue: string.Empty,
      defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
      propertyChanged: TitleTextPropertyChanged);

    private static void TitleTextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (ToolBarCustomeXaml)bindable;
        control.Lable1.Text = newValue?.ToString(); //Label1 es parte del xaml es el x:Name
    }

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return GetValue(ImageSourceProperty) as ImageSource; }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ImageSource),
      typeof(ImageSource),
      typeof(ToolBarCustomeXaml),
      defaultValue: null,
      defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
      propertyChanged: ImageSourcePropertyChanged);

    private static void ImageSourcePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (ToolBarCustomeXaml)bindable;
        control.Image1.Source = (ImageSource)newValue; //Image1 es parte del xaml
    }

    public ToolBarCustomeXaml()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```